# Questions about calendar and calendar events

Tags: c#, calendar

Right now i am trying to make a calendar sort of site, and right now I got two things that I need to get through before at all being able to continue, and quite frankly not sure how to do it, if there even is a way to do it.

First things first, is there a way to line up the week days (monday, tuesday..) with the different dates, or does it need to be hardcoded each time?

Second, since I am creating the dates using a for-loop, is there a way I can have the Edit button on each date send a ID to a form, letting it know which date they put the reminder on?

The code creating the days:

```
<%      
    var days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2015, 11);

    for (int i = 1; i < days; i++)
    {
        Response.Write("<div class='week'>");
        Response.Write("<ul>");
        Response.Write("<li>");
        Response.Write(i);
        Response.Write("<a href='WebForm1.aspx?setReminder=1'> <img src='editIcon.png' alt='Set reminder'> </a>");

        if (Request["reminderForm"] == "hiddenValue")
        {
            Response.Write(Request["reminderName"]);
        }

        Response.Write("</li>");
        Response.Write("</ul>");
        Response.Write("</div>");
    }

    var setReminder = Request["setReminder"];        
    if(setReminder != null) { 
%>
```

..as well as the form where you set the reminder itself :

```
<h3>Set a reminder/event</h3>

<form method="POST" action="WebForm1.aspx">

    <input type="hidden" name="reminderForm" value="hiddenValue" />
    Event name: <input type="text" name="reminderName" /> <br />
    Event date: <input type="text" name="reminderDate" /> <br />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Set</button> <br />

</form> 
        <% } %>
```

Comment: Please take more care over making your code readable. I expect you don't have the random indentation and huge amounts of vertical whitespace in your real source code, so why subject readers here to it? (I've edited it now to be a lot more readable.

Comment: Some formations may have broke when pasting it over here, however, I do find it more readable with vertical spaces myself. @JonSkeet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question. If you make every day in the selected month a DateTime then you can change the DateTimeFormat and specify what you want it to look like.

> First things first, is there a way to line up the week days (monday,
>   tuesday..) with the different dates, or does it need to be hardcoded
>   each time?

Examples can be found here:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If you line up the DateTime objects with the .ToShortDateTime() function you can add a string for the format in the brackets.

> "dddd" = 2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> Monday (en-US)

This will get you the name of the day.

I am not sure about your second question but I hope this helps so far.

Here's a quick example on how to get the weekdays:

```
public void Test()
    {
        int month = 11;
        int year = 2015;
        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month); //This will give us days = 30

        for (int i = 1; i < days; i++)
        {
            string dayteTime = new DateTime(year, month, i).ToString("D");
            //This will create the following Output:
            //Sunday, 1. November 2015
            //Monday, 2. November 2015
            //.... this can be added to a list or how ever you need the days.
        }
    }
```

Comment: As someone rather new to C# I appreciate your answer, but I'm not sure what to put where. Looked at the link but didn't give me much.

Comment: Give me some time. I will create an example

Comment: Is this what you need ?

Comment: Looks like it, getting a CS1513: } expected error code which seems to react on the public void test() {} tag, though.

Comment: I am not sure how to format it for your case just try to copy my logic and insert it where you need it. You don't need to implemt the method itself. Just take the logic.

Comment: Ah, got it working now. Doesn't sem to be printing the weekdays though, just "the 1st of november" for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94191/discussion-between-xariez-and-fe-de).